# Extracting latest non-NA value in data frame based on grouping

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data frame that looks like the following:

```
 Year   Day  ID   V1  V2 .... 
 2003   35  1102  3   6
 2003   35  1103  5   NA
 2003   35  1104  8   100
 .....
 2003   40  1102  NA  8
 2003   40  1103  NA  10
 2003   40  1104  9   NA
 .....
 .....
 2018   49  1104  5   NA
 .....
 2018   50  1102  3   6
 2018   50  1103  7   NA
 2018   50  1104  NA  100
```

I would like to build a data frame that extracts, for each combination of Year and ID, the the latest (high value per the Day column) non-NA value in V1, V2... Based on the above data set, for Year = 2018 and ID = 1104, I would like to extract V1 = 5 (on Day = 49) and V2 = 100 (on Day = 50). If all values for that Year and ID combination are NA then I would like it to return NA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can create a function which gives us the latest non-NA value based on `Day` for each `Vn` column

```
get_last_non_NA_value <- function(x) {
   x[which.max(cumsum(!is.na(x)))]
}
```

and then apply that function for each `Year` and `ID`

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(Year, ID) %>%
  summarise_at(vars(V1:V2), funs(get_last_non_NA_value(.[order(Day)])))


#    Year  ID    V1    V2
#  <int> <int> <int> <int>
#1  2003  1102     3     8
#2  2003  1103     5    10
#3  2003  1104     9   100
#4  2018  1102     3     6
#5  2018  1103     7    NA
#6  2018  1104     5   100
```

---

**EDIT**

If we also want to extract corresponding `Day` for each value, we can change the function to return both values as comma-separated string

```
get_last_non_NA_value <- function(x, y) {
   ind <- which.max(cumsum(!is.na(x[order(y)])))
   paste(x[ind], y[ind], sep = ",")
}
```

and then use `cSplit` to separate these comma separated values into different columns.

```
library(dplyr)
library(splitstackshape)
cols <- c("V1", "V2")

df %>%
 group_by(Year, ID) %>%
 summarise_at(cols, funs(get_last_non_NA_value(., Day))) %>%
 cSplit(cols) %>%
 rename_at(vars(contains("_1")), funs(sub("_1", "_last_value", .))) %>%
 rename_at(vars(contains("_2")), funs(sub("_2", "_days", .)))


#   Year   ID V1_last_value V1_days V2_last_value V2_days
#1: 2003 1102             3      35             8      40
#2: 2003 1103             5      35            10      40
#3: 2003 1104             9      40           100      35
#4: 2018 1102             3      50             6      50
#5: 2018 1103             7      50            NA      50
#6: 2018 1104             5      49           100      50
```

Note that `rename_at` part renames the columns for better understanding of what value it holds, you can skip that part if you are not interested in renaming columns.

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(Year = c(2003L, 2003L, 2003L, 2003L, 2003L, 2003L, 
2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L), Day = c(35L, 35L, 35L, 40L, 40L, 
40L, 49L, 50L, 50L, 50L), ID = c(1102L, 1103L, 1104L, 1102L, 
1103L, 1104L, 1104L, 1102L, 1103L, 1104L), V1 = c(3L, 5L, 8L, 
NA, NA, 9L, 5L, 3L, 7L, NA), V2 = c(6L, NA, 100L, 8L, 10L, NA, 
NA, 6L, NA, 100L)), .Names = c("Year", "Day", "ID", "V1", "V2"
), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -10L))
```

Comment: I don't think I'm getting the right output with this solution, for Year = 2003 and ID = 1102, V1 should be 3 and V2 should be 8 not 6. The output is also not correct for 2003 / 1103 but is correct for 2018 / 1104. I didn't specify this in my OP but is there a way to add the Day value that corresponds to the last non-NA value for each of V1, V2....?

Comment: @Yandle The function didn't need `decreasing = TRUE` part in `order`. I have updated the answer. We can't have `Day` value for each group since those values can differ for each of `V1`, `V2`...

Comment: Sorry I meant if getting the corresponding day is possible if we could have multiple Day columns (i.e. Day_V1, Day_V2 etc.) for each variable

Comment: @Yandle Edited the answer. See if it is helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `dplyr`
Assuming you want max for V1 and V2

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
    group_by(Year, ID) %>%
    summarise(Day = max(Day, na.rm = TRUE),
              V1 = max(V1, na.rm = TRUE),
              V2 = max(V2, na.rm = TRUE))
```

If for V1 and V2, you want first non-NA then

```
df %>%
    group_by(Year, ID) %>%
    summarise(Day = max(Day, na.rm = TRUE),
              V1 = first(setdiff(V1, NA)),
              V2 = first(setdiff(V1, NA)))
```

Comment: `df %>% group_by(Year, ID) %>% summarise_all(~max(.,na.rm = T))` can save you some typping

Comment: I'm actually looking for the last non-NA so I'm guessing I just replace the "first" function with "last"? With regards to Day, the last non-NA value may or may not correspond to the max of Day (which has no missing values). Is there a way to extract the Day corresponding to the last non-NA value for each of V1, V2....